Stewardship of an ecryptfs tag
I am one of the authors and the current maintainer of eCryptfs, a cryptographic filesystem for Linux.  It's been in the Linux kernel since about 2006.  It's the cryptographic filesystem used by default on Ubuntu if you choose to "Encrypt your Home Directory", as well as by ChromeOS.
I'd like to move the eCryptfs community's interactive, frequently-asked-questions and answers from Launchpad to crypto.stackexchange.com (or to another site, if there's a more appropriate one).
I certainly don't intend for this to be a support forum but rather a repository for quality Q&A content.
Note that I'm doing something similar for another open source project I maintain (byobu) migrating those questions and answers to superuser.com, and I agree to abide by those same guidelines agreed upon.
Here are the guidelines I propose directing eCryptfs users with:
On-Topic on Stack Exchange sites: How and Why?

Questions that are Ubuntu-specific eCryptfs (e.g., Ubuntu Encrypted Home or Private directories)?

Ask Ubuntu!

Questions that are distribution-agnostic, or generally applicable to Linux/Unix eCryptfs, from a user perspective?

Unix and Linux Stack Exchange!

Questions about eCryptfs use cases, threat assessments, appropriate and inappropriate uses?

IT Security Stack Exchange!

Questions about the math or cryptography within eCryptfs?

Cryptography Stack Exchange!


Off-Topic on Stack Exchange:

Errors, bugs, ideas, feature requests, potential vulnerabilities?  File a bug!

Launchpad Bugs!

Looking for source code?

Kernel Git and User space Bzr

We suck and you hate us?

Mailing list!

We're awesome and you love us?

Google +1!

Wanna chat?

IRC!


Thanks,
Dustin

Weighing in as an Ask Ubuntu mod and mainly to echo Ninefingers: it sounds like a plan but don't expect or try to fit everything on one site.

For technical process (eg "How to I encrypt this in Ubuntu?"), Ask Ubuntu wants those.
As above for non-Ubuntu, to Unix & Linux
For underlying theory Crypto and Security are probably better audiences.

I'm honestly not sure what to do with questions that are atomically about eCryptfs. Eg "Can eCryptfs do X?" with no mention of platform. Given it's a Linux-only project, I would be tempted to suggest U&L but one of their mods might want to say if they fancy that (or not).
It does also depend on what you want but I don't think you'll get the best out of this if you plonk everything on one site.

"Can eCryptfs do X?" is probably fine for UL; the filesystem only works on Linux, so it's on-topic for us regardless of distro
